# Change the line color with fill_between

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot in matplotlib that look like this:

[image]

I have two arrays with values - x and y. When x is greater than y, it fills in white, if not, the color should be blue. However, I want the line to be the same color as the array that is being draw. Something like this:

[image]

For that I tried this piece of code:

```
f3_ax7.fill_between(all_mins, x, y, where=(x > y), color = 'white', alpha=0.4, interpolate=True, linewidth=10, edgecolor='white')

f3_ax7.fill_between(all_mins, y, x, where=(x > y), color = 'blue', alpha=0.4, interpolate=True, linewidth=10, edgecolor='blue')
```

But the color is always blue.

Any idea what is wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: Are you overwriteing the white color? or do you whant white dots aswell? What is happening when you use red instead of white?

Comment: After the two fill_between commands, you could add a line plot: `f3_ax7.plot(all_mins, x, color = 'white', alpha=0.4, linewidth=10, edgecolor='white')`